# Publish on Xbap to IIS on Windows Server 2003

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, xbap

Ive programmed an Xbap Application and published it to Windows XP computer without any problem. Now I want to publish the Xbap application to a Computer running Windows Server 2003. I do'nt get any failure when I´m publish the application, but when I try to browse the application I got failure and I cant browse the application.

When i try to run http://localhost/MyApp/setup.exe, It says that the file could not be found...

I there someting else I have to do when publish to a Windows Server 2003 Computer compared to Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like the problem here was the MIME Types in IIS. By register the followign MIME Types in IIS solved my problem:

- .manifest  application/manifest
- .xaml  application/xaml+xml
- .application  application/x-ms-application
- .xbap  application/x-ms-xbap
- .deploy  application/octet-stream
- .xps  application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument

For more information how to do this, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752346.aspx#content_expiration

- List item